# MySql SSL configuration - Client section

Tags: linux, mysql, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to secure my work with a SSL connection between some applications and my dabtabases.

In a first time, i search how to create certificates, and i do something like this :

### Creation of the folder :

```
[...]$ mkdir certificats && cd certificats
```

### CA :

```
[...]$ openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem

[...]$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 500 -key ca-key.pem > ca-cert.pem
```

### Server :

```
[...]$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 500 -nodes 
       -keyout server-key.pem > server-req.pem

[...]$ openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 500
       -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > server-cert.pem
```

### Client :

```
[...]$ openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 500 -nodes 
       -keyout client-key.pem > client-req.pem

[...]$ openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 500 -CA ca-cert.pem 
       -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > client-cert.pem
```

I answer to all questions asked like this : same answer to the three files except for "common name" (i saw somewhere than this can cause problem).

### Server's configuration :

After that, i did this :

```
[...]$ vim /etc/my.cnf
```

to add the following rules (on the [mysqld]) :

```
ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/certs_mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/certs_mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/ssl/certs_mysql/server-key.pem
```

Now, when i log into a normal account, i can see using

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
```

than ssl is enabled. (see 3 path + 2 'YES')

### Connection :

So now, for connection, i have to use :

```
[...]$ mysql -u user -ppassword -h localhost --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem 
             --ssl-key=client-key.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem
```

right ? (the user is on 'REQUIRE SSL' mode).

But it doesnt worked well :

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)
```

If i remove the "ca-cert.pem" from the connection, this work "well". i can connect, and i can saw "Ssl_cipher" with something like "xxx-xxx-AES264-xxx" when i wrote "\s".

So, i tried to add :

```
[client]

ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/certs_mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/certs_mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/ssl/certs_mysql/client-key.pem
```

But when i add "ssl-x" in the "client" section, mysql stop BUT won't restart using

```
[...]$ service mysqld restart
```

Why can't i wrote ssl configuration in the client section ?

I try a connection to my databases using a PHP file, when i used the 3 files, the connection is refused, but if i only used "client-key.pem" and "client-cert.pem", i'm connected.

i saw somewhere than using

```
[...]$ cat client-cert.pem server-cert.pem > ca-cert.pem
```

can solved the problem but so the ca-cert used contained 2 certs ?

So the problem, i though, is in ca-cert.pem ? Not recognize as a "real certificate" so the connection si refused ? But why can't i used [client] ?

Thanks in advance for you answers

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too long to post as a comment, even though it's not a complete answer. But if we get this info, we can get a few steps further. So here goes:

In order to resolve an SSL issue, I'd like to start by taking mysql out of the equation. So start by using only SSL to connect, like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:MYSQLPORTNR -cert client.pem -key client-key.pem -CAfile ca-cert.pem
```

where MYSQLPORTNR should of course be replaced with the port number that you're running mysql on. Then add the output of this to your post.

Comment: Here the result of the command you gave me ::      `CONNECTED(00000003)
140235766978376:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:699:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 113 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---`